# ng-options result in two separate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a select using ng-options to serve up results. I can get it produce one of the json elements to a div, but i cannot seem to get it to do it for another. What am I missing?

HTML Code:

```
 <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="select_container">
                                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOption_1" ng-options="select_array.value as select_array.displayName for select_array in select_array"></select>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">{{selectedOption_1}}</td>
                                <td colspan="3">{{selectedOption_1}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Angular Code:

```
 $scope.select_array = [
    {value: '1', region:'London', displayName: 'display_1'},
    {value: '2', region:'London', displayName: 'display_2'},
    {value: '3', region:'London', displayName: 'display_3'},
];

$scope.selectedOption_1 = '123,285';
```

So what I would like to have happen, is when you select an option, have it populate value in the first div, and region in the second. And have that data change based on which option you select. Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, You will to have map your entire object as a value of an option.

```
<table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="select_container">
                                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOption_1" ng-options="select_array as select_array.displayName for select_array in select_array"></select>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">{{selectedOption_1.value}}</td>
                                <td colspan="3">{{selectedOption_1.region}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```